# AES Algorithm Encrypte decrypte

Tags: c#, encryption

return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(ence); - the name 'ence' does not exist in the current context.
I am trying to decrypt text from a file that I am already encrypt.

```
public static string Decrypte(string encrypted)
        {

            var Check = Form1.verify;
            string password = Form1.password;
            if (Check == password)
            {
                byte[] textBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
                AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
                endec.BlockSize = 128;
                endec.KeySize = 256;
                endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
                endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
                endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateDecryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
                byte[] ence = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
                icrypt.Dispose();
                return Convert.ToString(ence);
            }

            if (Form1.verify == password)
            {
                return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(ence);
                    
            }
            else if (Form1.verify != password)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Use originas key file");
            }

            return encrypted;
        }
```

Comment: This is rather confused. Your first two `if`s seem to always be true together or false together but if that's so, you have two different `return` statements that you apparently want?

Comment: The compiler error is because `ence` only exists in the scope of the first `if` block.  You can declare it before that block.  *However*, logically none of this makes sense.  In the current code, that second `if` block should never execute anyway.  So I guess the simpler solution would be to just remove that second `if` block entirely?